# When does a Deezer access token expire?

Tags: api, deezer

I noticed that an access token (requesting offline access) changes if the application asks for additional permissions and the user grants them; is this the only case where an access token can expire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offline_access access token never expires. So indeed, the only way it can change is when you request for additional permissions.

Comment: thanks, it took me a lot of time to find this answer. You should probably clarify this point in your documentation. cf. offline_access : Application may access user data at any time